# Process multiple input rows using UDJC step in PDI

Tags: pentaho

I have a requirement to do the following.
The input provided is as shown below

```
State city
NY    joe 
NY    jane 
LA    zorro 
LA    steve
```

and the output should be

```
State city
NY    joe, jane
LA    steve, zorro
```

How to make this possible? I guess I have to process multiple input rows but when I try to read a new row using the `getRow()` method for the second time it's throwing array-out-of-bounds exception.... Please help me regarding this.. TIA

Here's the logic I've tried...

```
String cities;
Object[][] r = new Object[10][];
static int j;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{

for(;j<10||(r[j]=getRow())!=null;j++)
{
return true;
}

cities=get(Fields.In, "CITY").getString(r[0]);

int i;
for(i=1;r[i]!=null;i++)
{
if(get(Fields.In, "STATE").getString(r[i-1])==get(Fields.In, "STATE").getString(r[i])){

cities=cities+","+get(Fields.In, "CITY").getString(r[i]);
}
else{
Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(new Object[4],1);
get(Fields.Out, "STATE").setValue(outputRow, get(Fields.In, "STATE").getString(r[i-1]));
get(Fields.Out, "CITIES").setValue(outputRow, cities);
putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);
cities=get(Fields.In, "CITY").getString(r[i]);
}
}
Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(new Object[4],1);
get(Fields.Out, "STATE").setValue(outputRow, get(Fields.In, "STATE").getString(r[i-1]));
get(Fields.Out, "CITIES").setValue(outputRow, cities);
putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a UDJC for that. Sort your input set by "State" with either a Sort Rows step, or an ORDER BY clause in the SQL if using a Table Input step. Use a Group By step and set State for your Group Field, then specify "city" in the Subject field for your aggregate and use `Concatenate strings separated by ,` for your aggregate type.